# Triggering CSS3 Transform on browser resize

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have been playing with animated CSS3 Media Queries, yes I know their practical use is questionable but it is fun. Anyways, I can get boxes/divs/selectors to [transition/expand/contract](http://theboywhocriedfox.com/demo/animate-transitions-with-media-queries/) etc on browser resize but I am having problems with transforms. What I am trying to do is make a div flip or rotate at certain resolutions.

Think of it as an iPad changing from landscape to portrait and a div flipping when this happens.

Is this actually possible and if so what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? I'm testing it in Chrome 16 and it works.

Comment: On page load it works for me in Chrome, but after page load and on window resize it won't set-off the transform. With Media Queries I can get normal CSS3 transitions to work e.g.divs expanding/contracting on browser resize but I don't understand why it doesn't work for the transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have it working now. Based on post-erasmus' css I was able to tweak it and get it working 100%. Here's the code:

```
 .test{width: 400px; height: 200px; 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
transition:all .2s linear;
-o-transition:all .2s linear;
-moz-transition:all .2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 319px){
    .test{
            background-color: orange;
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 700px){
    .test{
            background-color: green; 

    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .test{
            background-color: red; 
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1201px){
    .test{
            background-color: blue;

    }   
}
```

Of course, you need to add the other vendor specific prefixes. When you animate a property, you need to specify both the beginning and ending state. So it seems that leaving out the transform will reset the property to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using media queries?

```
.test{
        background-color: blue; 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ie-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        margin: -26px -26px -26px -26px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 700px){
        .test{
                background-color: green; 
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ie-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                margin: -26px -26px -26px -26px;
        }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1200px){
        .test{
                background-color: red; 
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ie-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                margin: -26px -26px -26px -26px;
        }
}
```

With the appropriate (additional) transforms for ie, firefox, etc. It appears to work.

I put together a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/a8WCA/).

Comment: Yep. They work perfectly for everything bar these transforms. I was hoping to get around it by having my site using media queries while the transforms using jQuery+CSS.

Comment: The media queries are almost working perfectly for me. The only rotation that's not happening is the one that should be happening at the lowest width. post_erasmus is missing the -webkit-transition call in his css.

Comment: When you say working perfectly are they rotating as well as changing color? Maybe I have been staring at this too long and my brain has given up but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Lol, I know the feeling and yes. But it's not happening for the transition from red to green. The color changes but it doesn't rotate. Have you tried clearing your cache? Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/QYb77/

Comment: You might also try slowing down the transitions.  While the transformation was easy for me to spot in firefox, it was so fast as to be almost undetectable in chome. I tested with 90deg and -90deg rotations at first to make sure it was actually happening.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the fiddles both work although yours (Alex) has all three firing.  I think I was going cross-eyed staring at it for so long. I really hope it wasn't the cache. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah I posted the answer with the code below. It also provides a bit of an explanation as to why it works.