# CSS Transtions Twitter's Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to add transitions to my css for smooth responsive action but cant seem to get it to work. Can anyone enlighten me ? Do i need to override something ?

```
    body{
    padding-top: 60px;
     transition:all .2s linear; 
    -o-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:all .2s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start reading here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

> CSS3 transitions are effects that let an element gradually change from one style to another.

So you have define the style change.

> The effect will start when the specified CSS property changes value. A typical CSS property >change would be when a user mouse-over an element:

Often a :hover is used to trigger the change. For example [Triggering CSS3 Transform on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194708/triggering-css3-transform-on-browser-resize) shows you, also a media query can be used the trigger the style change.

So first define the effect, duration etc.:

```
body{
     padding-top: 0px;//begin state, you don't have to declare this cause 0px is default

     transition:padding-top 2s linear; 
    -o-transition:padding-top 2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:padding-top 2s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:padding-top 2s linear;
}
```

Note a replace all with padding-top. using all will check changes for all possible styles, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254934(v=vs.85).aspx for a list of them, which take unnecessary computation time.

second define your style change:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    body{
          padding-top: 200px;
    }
}
```

see: http://bootply.com/105331